# Add a listener on Edit Text android? C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-edittext, listener

I'm currently developing for `Android` using `C#` and `Xamarin`.

I have an `EditText` box within my app where the user can input information. How can I add a listener that will see if the user is actually typing in it? The reason I need this is to link it to analytics, so I can see how many users actually type information.

Thanks!

Comment: How would you capture the information from the box if you were going to, say, copy it to a label in your view? Search on `android read text from textbox` to find a multitude of StackOverflow answers that might help.

Answer (score 11):

```
editText.TextChanged += (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e) => {

   textView.Text = e.Text.ToString ();

};
```

Is what I believe you are looking for, more information [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/edittext/capture_user_input_text/)

Answer (score 3):

Implement the `ITextWatcher` on your `Activity`, `Fragment` subclass or create a new `Java.Lang.Object` class:

```
public class TextWatcher : Java.Lang.Object, ITextWatcher
{
    public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
    {
        //
    }

    public void BeforeTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
        //
    }

    public void OnTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Add the listener to your `EditText` instance:

```
editText.AddTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher());
```

Answer (score 0):

use `AddTextWatcher` to listen the EditText in android

Answer (score 0):

add text change listener and in afterTextChanged Method, save the device's mac address to the server . Because MAC address is always unique

```
 Field1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

       @Override    
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int count, int after) {
       }

       @Override    
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int before, int count) {

      });
```

you can count number of users with the help of number of mac addresses